90's (or 2000's) TV series about a group of paranormal investigators (fiction)
There is this TV series which I remember vague pieces time to time. I'm not sure if it's from the nineties or the 2000s. The two main characters, a male and a female, were part of a paranormal investigation group. No, it's not The X-Files nor Fringe. I guess the guy wore round glasses.
I remember some things about two stories. One seemed to be paranormal but wasn't. It was about a "haunted" house, with a rocking chair and an audio system linked somehow to it (I guess the rocking chair didn't move by itself, but when a person sit there and start moving, the faulty electrical system started the music). Also, with the rocking chair moving, the tables from the floor began to scratch themselves, bringing a certain smell to the air thanks to the friction.
The other story was paranormal, about a piece of fabric from the clothes of a religious man. The fabric had indeed healing properties, but each time it was used to heal, it degraded itself, losing part of it. For the end of the episode there was a debate including the main characters about healing or not a certain person with the last piece of the fabric. I tried to find the series from this fact, the most certain I have, but most of Google results weren't related even to TV.
The series were most probably American, less probably Canadian, very unlikely British. About the network... I have some kind of memory link with Sony Entertainment from Latin America (I guess because of the ads narrator), but I'm not sure.
I tried to ask Gemini (Google's AI) and, while most of the suggestions were quite off, I highlight one of them: "Beyond Reality". It's plot seemed similar to the series I'm tring to find. One episode in particular was about a healing person with degrading powers, not a fabric.
I added "fiction" on the post title to distinguish the series from shows like "Ghost Hunters".

Warehouse 13?  Could that be it?

Didnt edit my reply above fast enough I was going to add:   Or Haven have similar concepts.

@Brad Sorry, it's not Warehouse 13 (the group from the series I'm trying to find doesn't look for lost special objects from a warehouse) nor Haven (it's not about a town, but an organization in a city (sadly, I don't remember which city)). Thanks anyway.

I remember the cloth having healing powers - but the age meant that it degraded. From memory, it ended up being about 2 inches square, and kept in a bowl of heavier-than-air noble gas (krypton?) to preserve it.

My mind brought up "Burning Zone", but that was mostly about diseases, and the episode summaries on IMDB didn't seem to have one about a healing relic.

And after a brief dive into "1990's supernatural TV shows", I think that the one with the cloth is "Mysterious Ways". Male and female protagonist: check; paranormal investigations: kind of (he seeks out miracles and wonders; round glasses: no.

Poltergeist the Legacy? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0115317/?ref_=nm_knf_t_3 Just a thought.

If none of the paranormal activity turned out actually to be paranormal, I wonder if this is Jonathan Creek? (Male and female protagonists Jonathan and Madeline, though the series is British which you reckon is unlikely.) The first ep sounds kind of familiar, the second one doesn't.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psi_Factor perhaps?

WAG-Could it have been "Sleepwalkers"? https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118464/?ref_=nm_flmg_t_99_act

@enkorvaks "Mysterious Ways", that is! Thank you! I did now a quick search with that title, and saw the pictures of the main characters very familiar. Even found the episode of the healing fabric with its summary in IMDB, "The Greater Good" (with a picture of the guy wearing round glasses - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0655368/mediaviewer/rm548605953/?ref_=tt_ov_i). I had too the memory of the fabric being isolated, but less vivid than yours. I didn't remember that the guy was Adrian Pasdar, who I've seen in Heroes and Agents of SHIELD.

As identified in the comments, the show is Mysterious Ways (https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0247119 ), starring Adrian Pasdar and Rae Dawn Chong.
The episode with the healing cloth is "The Greater Good".

And for those who are wondering about the episode with the rocking chair, it's "Friends in Need".
